# Rails Model Validation: i need validates_inclusion_of with case sensitive false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, case-sensitive, validates-uniqueness-of

Here is code which is not working

```
    class WeekDay < ActiveRecord::Base
           validates_inclusion_of :day, :in => %w(sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday), :case_sensitive => false
    end
```

Currently i have all of days in db except sunday. I am trying to add "Sunday", and getting errors "is not included in the list".

Comment: Interesting, I see the same thing using the new style validations: `validates :day, inclusion:{in:%w(one two), case_sensitive:false}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

validates_inclusion_of does not have a case_sensitive argument, so you can create your own validator(if you are using Rails 3):

```
class DayFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless %w(sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday).include?(value.downcase)
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not a proper day.") 
    end
  end
end
```

and save this in your lib directory as:

```
lib/day_format_validator.rb
```

Then in your model, you can have:

```
validates :day, :day_format => true
```

Just make sure rails loads this lib file on startup by putting this in your config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, answer is represented very nicely.

Comment: If you want to use the standard, internationalized Rails error message, do `object.errors.add(attribute, I18n.t!("errors.messages.inclusion"))`, which will use the built-in Rails locale file (eg, here's the english one for version 4.2.5: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml#L9)

Answer (score 2):

```html
class WeekDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  before_validation :downcase_fields
  
  validates_inclusion_of :day, :in => %w(sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday)
    
  def downcase_fields
    self.day.downcase!
  end
  
end
```

This downcases the field before running the validation

Answer (score -1):

A little simple solution if not worried about separating validations in lib

```
    class WeekDay < ActiveRecord::Base
        validate :validate_day
            def validate_day
            if !self.day.nil?
                errors.add(:day, "is not included in the list") unless  %w(sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday).include?(self.day.downcase)
                    end
            end 
     end
```